# C++ OpenCV: Computing Image Stats for Image Batches

Tags: c++, opencv, pytorch, porting

[This](https://kozodoi.me/python/deep%20learning/pytorch/tutorial/2021/03/08/image-mean-std.html) blog post shows us how to normalize image pixel values using PyTorch's dataloader. Using a DataLoader to do the calculation is important, as it allows the standard deviation to be calculated across batches (not the overall stddev).

For performance reasons, I need to port this code to a C++ version, and I have OpenCV in mind. Does OpenCV have something similar to PyTorch's dataloader that makes batch calculations easier?

This particular snippet caught my eye:

```
# loop through images
for inputs in tqdm(image_loader):
    psum    += inputs.sum(axis        = [0, 2, 3])
    psum_sq += (inputs ** 2).sum(axis = [0, 2, 3])
```

The author stated that setting the **axis=[0, 2, 3]** allows the sum/sum_sq to be calculated with respect to axis=1. The dimensions of inputs is **[batch_size x 3 x image_size x image_size]**, so we need to make sure we aggregate values per each RGB channel separately. Can a similar calculation be done on a cv::Mat object?

Comment: If its possible to do this operation in Python with OpenCV, then in C++ also it is possible. So maybe you can try with Python first and if it works, then port it to C++.

Comment: The image stats calculation is done with Torch, not OpenCV.